# reading content from multiple files into array php

Tags: php, html, arrays, file, multidimensional-array

I am struggling with this problem i can't solve.

i have a sequential text file with the following records structured like this:

```
    First Name : ......;
    Last Name: ......;
    Contact Details:.....;
    Email Address:.....;
    Enquirer Type:.....;
    Contact Method:....;
    Message:....';
    |----------|
    First Name : ......;
    ..............
```

I am having trouble displaying the information in a table within the container

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/session_Style.css">
    <title>User Session</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div id="table">
      <?php

$filename = "Contacts.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$fileContent = explode('|----------|', $content);

foreach ($fileContent as $number => $contact) {

  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr><th colspan="2">Contact '.$number.'</th></tr>';

  foreach ($contact as $detail) {
    $detail = explode(':',$detail);
    echo '<tr><td>'.$detail[0].'</td><td>'.$detail[1].'</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
?>
      </div>      
      <div class="logout">
        <h1>User Details</h1>
        <form method="post" action="">
          <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Log Out" onclick="document.location.href='home-page.html';"></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this the right way to implement the solutions provided by you guys? Or is there a way it can be done more efficiently?

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant file - assumed 'file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_HTML\contact-us.php on line 16

Notice: Use of undefined constant filename - assumed 'filename' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_HTML\contact-us.php on line 16.... Line 16 is the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$fileContent[$filenumber] = explode(';',file_get_contents($filename));
```

$fileContent is an array with file numbers as keys. So the data of the file contact_1 will be stored in $fileContent[1].
explode() will make an array with the file contents, separated by the ';'.
You can now for example access the first name of contact_2 with $fileContent[2][0]. This will return: "First Name : ....."

---

Now for the table:

```
foreach ($fileContent as $number => $contact) {

  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr><th colspan="2">Contact '.$number.'</th></tr>';

  foreach ($contact as $detail) {

    $detail = explode(':',$detail);
    echo '<tr><td>'.$detail[0].'</td><td>'.$detail[1].'</td></tr>';

  }

  echo '</table>';

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Now with that solved, my next problem is displaying them in a table on html. I know the basics of tables but how would one implement something like that?

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock I've updated the scenario. Please share your thoughts

Comment: Looks fine so far, but remember to place php code between <?php and ?> properly. You haven't done that yet.

Comment: Before `</head>` you have `>`, I think that should be `?>`. After `<div id="table">`, the `<?php` is missing now, and before the `</div>`, another `?>` is missing.

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock .. Check out my comment on the original post please